# How to install web3 on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, npm, web3js

I wanna install web3 on my Ubuntu 18.04.
I've tried:

```
sudo npm install -g web3
```

which raises:

> npm ERR! git clone --template=/home/sj/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates
> --mirror git@github.com:web3-js/WebSocket-Node.git /home/sj/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-web3-js-WebSocket-Node-git-polyfill-globalThis-504e07ba:
> undefined npm ERR! git clone
> --template=/home/sj/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git@github.com:web3-js/WebSocket-Node.git
> /home/sj/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-web3-js-WebSocket-Node-git-polyfill-globalThis-504e07ba:
> undefined npm ERR! Linux 5.0.0-29-generic npm ERR! argv
> "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "web3" npm ERR! node
> v8.10.0 npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2 npm ERR! code ENOGIT
>
> npm ERR! not found: git npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed using git. npm ERR!
> This is most likely not a problem with npm itself. npm ERR! Please
> check if you have git installed and in your PATH.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> npm ERR!     /home/sj/npm-debug.log

I've also tried:

```
sudo npm install -g web3 --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Answer (score 1):

I've updated repository and installed git:

```
# sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
# sudo apt-get -y install curl git vim build-essential
```